# How to calculate the convolution of $\operatorname{sinc}t$ and another function?

Tags: integration, convolution

I have for example this function: $B(t)=\cos(2\pi t)+2\sin(2\pi t)$

Now I have a LPF function: $H(t)=C\operatorname{sinc}(wt)$

I want to calculate this convolution:    $ y=(B*H)$

but I am finding problems doing this, I looked up how do the integral for the $\operatorname{sinc}$ function but not in convolution... and it was kinda of complicated, so I think there is something I am missing out...

Any hint? Thanks in advance.

update( is there is a way to do this with the help of fourier transform ? i think this is the trick maybe :/ )

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The transform of the convolution is the product of the transforms.

The transform of the cardinal sine is a square window.

The transform of the sinusoid is a pair of Dirac deltas.

Hence the product is either a pair of Dirac deltas, corresponding to the original sinusoid, or zero, depending on whether the Dirac fall inside the window or not.

Comment: by transform  you mean fourier transform ? if yes then i need to use Reverse transformation at the end right ?

Comment: @jasmin: yep, you can recognize that from the results.

Comment: ok i am gonna try this now ! thanks

Comment: i have a question : the fourier transform for $c*sinc(w0 *t)$ = $(C/(abs(w0)) rect(w/(2*pi*w0)) $ ?

Comment: @jasmin: dind't I write "The transform of the cardinal sine is a square window." ?

Comment: yes i know , but rect is a square window .. but i am asking about the constants if they are correct ?

Comment: @jasmin: no idea, these are details. Lookup a table.